# Отображает related problem при подставлении переменной вместо стрингового значения в аннотации Appium @AndroidFindBy ( id = моя переменная)

Tags: java, переменные, relation, appium, android-testing

Изучаю Аппиум. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в IDEA отобажает Related problem над переменной, которую я использую для сохранения части ID. Дело в том, что первая часть ID элемента состоит из appPackagе, а вторая -это id элемента на экране аппиум. Мне нужно, чтоб первая часть была изменяемая. Я ее поместил в String переменную. И во всех классах моей программы это работате, кроме одного.

```
 public class BaseSetup {

    //обьявление переменных
    private DesiredCapabilities cb =new DesiredCapabilities();
    private static AndroidDriver ad =null;

    private String port = "4723";
    private String server = "127.0.0.1";

    **//тут я объявляю эту переменную, которая имеет значение для appPackage**
    protected String myapp = "com.covantex.mediker"; 


    @BeforeClass
    //публичный класс для вызова приватного класса
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        initDriver();
    }

    /* метод который будет возвращать драйвер для передачи его следующим страницам
    при переходе на другие активити
     а так же получения драйвера в пределах текущего активити */
    public AndroidDriver getDriver(){
        return ad;
    }

    //приватный класс с данными для запуска сессии
    private void initDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        //создание экземпляра класа для передачи парамеров запуска приложения на устройстве
        DesiredCapabilities ds =new DesiredCapabilities();

        ds.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"374c3291");
        ds.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        ds.setCapability( "appPackage", myapp);
        ds.setCapability( "appActivity", "com.meetMyDoc.ui.activity.LoginActivity");
        ds.setCapability("noReset",true );

        String url = "http://"+server+":"+port+"/wd/hub";


        //инициализация андроид райвера + ексепшин для отлова ошибок
        try{
            System.out.println("Драйвер проинициализирован с такими данными: " + url);
            ad = new AndroidDriver(new URL(url), ds);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException|MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Андроид драйвер не может быть проинициализирован :(");
        }System.out.println("Не инициализирован: " +ad);


    }
   }
```

От этого класса у меня наследуется драйвер.

```
// наследование от BaseSetup
public class Driver extends BaseSetup {
    protected AndroidDriver ad;

    //это конструктор, где происходит инициализация драйвера родителя
    protected Driver(){
        this.ad = super.getDriver();
    }
}
```

От драйвера наследуется MainPage, в котором я тоже использую переменную *myapp* как части id для нахождения элемента на экране.

```
public class MainPage extends Driver {



    public void clickBtn() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        MobileElement el3 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementById(myapp + ":id/btnLogin");
        el3.click();

    }

    public void sendCredentials()  throws InterruptedException{

        Thread.sleep(2500);

        //тут работает 
        MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementById( myapp + ":id/etUserName");
        el1.sendKeys("admin");

        // и тут работает
        MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) ad.findElementById( myapp + ":id/etPassword");
        el2.sendKeys("admin");

    }
```

Дальше я использую класс ScreenFormPF. Именно в нем я пытаюсь использовать **myapp** переменную. Именно в аннотации. И тут эта переменная подчеркивается красным. И пишет Related problem.

```
public class ScreenFormPF  extends MainPage {
    

    public ScreenFormPF( ){

        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(ad), this);
    }

    // тут уже не работает и подчеркивает красным
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.covantex.mediker:id/etUserName")
    private AndroidElement login;
    // тут тоже не работает
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.covantex.mediker:id/etPassword")
    private AndroidElement password;

}
```

Вопрос заключается в том, почему **Related problem**? и как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было перед обьявлением переменной поставить модификатор protected final

```
protected final String myapp = "com.myapp.medika";
```

Делается это для того, чтоб эта переменная никак не изменяла содержание.